# problems when declaring and assigning a value to a variable

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment, declaration

I have this class, with a variable called Palabra, but I don't know how to declare it.

```
public Paraula() {
    lletres = new char[MAXIM];
    llargaria = 0;
}

public static Paraula llegir() {
    Paraula nova = new Paraula();
    botarBlancs();
    while ((lletra != fiSequencia) && // No ha acabat la seqüència
            (lletra != blanc)) { // Hi ha prou espai
        nova.lletres[nova.llargaria++] = lletra;
        lletra = leerCarTeclado();
    }
    return nova;
}

public String toString() {
    String msg = "";
    for (int idx = 0; idx < llargaria; idx++) {
        msg += lletres[idx];
    }
    return msg;
}

public boolean esIgualA(Paraula b) {
    boolean iguals = llargaria == b.llargaria;
    for (int idx = 0; (idx < llargaria) && iguals; idx++) {
        iguals = lletres[idx] == b.lletres[idx];
    }
    return iguals;
}

public static boolean iguals(Paraula a, Paraula b) {
    return a.esIgualA(b);
}

public boolean buida() {
    return llargaria == 0;
}

public static void botarBlancs() {
    while (lletra == blanc) {
        lletra = leerCarTeclado();
    }
}

public static void botarParaula() throws Exception {
    while ((lletra != '.') && (lletra != blanc)) {
        lletra = leerCarTeclado();
    }
}
static public char leerCarTeclado() {
    char res = '.';
    if (frase != null) {
        res = frase[indice++];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Can someone help me??
I'm trying to declare two Paraula variables and then comparing them with one of the methods above, but I'm having trouble trying to assign a value to a Paraula. I'm really stuck and I need help. I think it can't be so complicated!!! But I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
Paraula tipo;
tipo=Paraula.llegir();
Paraula tipo1;
tipo1 = {'t','1'};  // here's where it doesn't work - (illegal start of expression)
```

How can I do it??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tipo1 = {'t','1'};  // here's where it doesn't work - (illegal start
>   of expression)

Use this construct instead:

```
Paraula tipo1;
tipo1 = { 
     lletres[0] = 't',
     llargaria = 1
};
```

Your code missed definition which constant belongs to which variable. Moreover, you tried to set `1` as **char** (`'1'`) and not an **int** ( `1`);

Comment: thank you, but writing tipo1= { reports an illegal start of expression. Any ideas? @Pavel

Comment: as an aclaration llargaria means length @Pavel , so I guess I have to set lletres[0], lletres[1] and then llargaria=2 , right?

Comment: @Maria yes, you need to do it this way. problem with that typo is that you need to specify, what do you assigning to what variable.

Comment: but how do I change it so it does't say illegal start of expression? @Pavel

Comment: @Maria this is exactly my code in my answer. I compiled it and code passed compilation without any trouble. Just replace your type1 assignment with my assignment. (And modify it as you need to)

Comment: Look at the answer below @Pavel

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this and reports an illegal start of expression

```
        Paraula tipo1;
        tipo1 = {
            Paraula.lletres[0] = 't';
            Paraula.lletres[1]='1';
            Paraula.llargaria = 2;
        }
```

Comment: Can you check this out, please? @Pavel Pája Halbich

Comment: This is not possible, since `lletres` and `llargaria` are not marked as static. May I ask: are you using Java or JavaScript? Because your syntax is more like JavaScript than Java.